# Mapped properties returning string array instead of Integer object in struts2

Tags: struts2

I have assigned Hahmap to the dropdowns.. each dropdown laues will be set into hashmap. when i try to get these values i am geeting values as string array instead of one object.so, i am not able to repopulate values if validation fails.
below is the code i am using to populate the values.

```
<s:iterator value="#actComments.lstEntities">
            <tr>
                <td width="15%" align="left"><s:textfield name="propType"
                    readonly="true" value="%{#attr.propertyTypeName}"
                    cssStyle="width:80px;font-size:11px;" /></td>
                <td width="85%" align="left"><s:select
                    name="hmMapComment[%{#attr.propertyTypeId}]"
                    cssStyle="font-size:11px;width:457px;margin-bottom:3px"
                    headerKey="0" headerValue="-- Select Comment --" list="comments"
                    listKey="commentId" listValue="commentText" /></td>
            </tr>
        </s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your getter declaration, do you have the HashMap declared to contain the appropriate types (i.e. HashMap< String, Integer >), or do you just have it as 'HashMap'?  It's my understanding that if you don't specify the types in the getter signature, the returned objects will be evaluated as strings.

---

Edit: if you're using below JDK 1.5, you can make a `'ClassName'-conversion.properties` file in your classpath for the appropriate action class (or maybe for the actComments, not sure).  That'll allow you to tell the type conversion code what type it is.

Add a line like

```
Element-lastEntities=com.yourcompany.WhateverObject
```

I'm not sure how you do subelements, whether you'd have to specify Element-actComments.lstEntities or something else.  I'd try fiddling with that.

Comment: Hi, I am using JDK1.4. so i can't use generics. Where do i need to declare it?do i need to use something like conversion. If so how to use it?